# What's the best way of checking whether a torch::Tensor is empty?

Tags: c++, torch, libtorch

I'm currently using the `has_storage()` method to check whether a tensor is empty or not, but I wonder if there is anything better other than this! and whether there are any implications involved in using this other than the fact that an initialized `torch::Tensor` always has a storage while an empty one doesn't!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After some digging, it turns out that the best solution for this is to use `.numel()` method which returns the number of elements a tensor has.
In summary:

- To know whether a tensor is allocated (type and storage), use defined().
- To know whether an allocated tensor has zero elements, use `numel()`
- To know whether a tensor is allocated and whether it has zero elements, use `defined()` and then `numel()`

Side note:
An empty tensor (that is the one created using `torch::Tensor t;` for example) returns zero when `.numel()` is used, while the size/sizes will result in an exception.

This is a perfect check for such cases where an empty tensor (in the sense I just explained above) is returned. One can simply do:

```cpp
if (!tensor.numel())
{
    std::cout<<"tensor is empty!" << std::endl;
    // do other checks you wish to do
}
```

[reference](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/43263#issuecomment-678320130)

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a small nuance here : all tensors do not have the same underlying implementation, and some implementations will have `has_storage` return `false` no matter what. This is in particular the case for sparse tensor (see [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/dd64e738c5cb191a5280b19635fe9941d6c0b95a/aten/src/ATen/SparseTensorImpl.cpp#L73)).

However I am not aware of any better way. Just be sure to correctly track your sparse tensors if you use them (and your [opaque tensors](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/93778f3b241a8f80897a7e61ac43aa2710e8e859/aten/src/ATen/OpaqueTensorImpl.h), if you ever need whatever they are ^^)

Comment: Thanks a lot again. really appreciate your time and well explained answers